# Workflow and Scheduling Framework for Spark with Scala in Maven Done with Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, workflow

I have created a spark project with Scala. Its a maven project with all dependency configured in POM.

Spark i am using as ETL. Source is file generated by API, All kind of transformation in spark then load it to cassandra.

Is there any Workflow software, which can used the jar to automate the process with email triggering, success or failure job flow.

May someone please help me..... is Airflow can be used for this purpose, i have used **SCALA and NOT Python**

Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism in Spark that will help. A cron job seems reasonable for your case. If you find yourself continuously adding dependencies to the scheduled job, try   [Azkaban](https://azkaban.github.io/)

one such example of shell script is :-

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /locm/spark_jobs

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/spark
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
export HADOOP_GROUP=hdfs

#export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/locm/spark_jobs/configs/*

CLASS=$1
MASTER=$2
ARGS=$3
CLASS_ARGS=$4
echo "Running $CLASS With Master: $MASTER With Args: $ARGS And Class Args: $CLASS_ARGS"

$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class $CLASS --master $MASTER --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 "application jar file"
```

You can even try using spark-launcher which can be used to start a spark application programmatically :-

First create a sample spark application and build a jar file for it.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object SparkApp extends App{
val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("spark-app")
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd=sc.parallelize(Array(2,3,2,1))
rdd.saveAsTextFile("result")
sc.stop()
}
```

This is our simple spark application, make a jar of this application using sbt assembly, now we make a scala application through which we start this spark application as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher

object Launcher extends App {

val spark = new SparkLauncher()
.setSparkHome("/home/knoldus/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
.setAppResource("/home/knoldus/spark_launcher-assembly-1.0.jar")
.setMainClass("SparkApp")
.setMaster("local[*]")
.launch();
spark.waitFor();

}
```

In the above code we use SparkLauncher object and set values for its like

setSparkHome(“/home/knoldus/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6”) is use to set spark home which is use internally to call spark submit.

.setAppResource(“/home/knoldus/spark_launcher-assembly-1.0.jar”) is use to specify jar of our spark application.

.setMainClass(“SparkApp”) the entry point of the spark program i.e driver program.

.setMaster(“local[*]”) set the address of master where its start here now we run it on loacal machine.

.launch() is simply start our spark application.

Its a minimal requirement you can also set many other configurations like pass arguments, add jar , set configurations etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot..... can we use Airflow or any external workflow management tool for this purpose. Please share your thoughts.